# Rust CXX library linked, but undefined error

Tags: c++, rust

I'm using [cxx](https://github.com/dtolnay/cxx) to write some C++ code, and then use this from rust. I also need to compile [cppparser](https://github.com/satya-das/cppparser), since my C++ code uses it. However I get undefined errors even after adding the correct link library path and the correct library to be linked. An equivalent C++ only program compiled with the same `-L` and `-l` compiles and runs successfully.

I even added the library path and the -l in both the cxx link and cargo link. I verified that the path `dir` in `build.rs` exists, and that it has `libcppparser.a`.

#### Cargo error:

```
warning: src/cpp/parser.cpp: In lambda function:
warning: src/cpp/parser.cpp:14:83: warning: unused parameter ‘errorStartPos’ [-Wunused-parameter]
warning:    14 |     parser.setErrorHandler([file](const char* errLineText, size_t lineNum, size_t errorStartPos, int lexerContext) -> void {
warning:       |                                                                            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: src/cpp/parser.cpp:14:102: warning: unused parameter ‘lexerContext’ [-Wunused-parameter]
warning:    14 |     parser.setErrorHandler([file](const char* errLineText, size_t lineNum, size_t errorStartPos, int lexerContext) -> void {
warning:       |                                                                                                  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: src/cpp/parser.cpp: In member function ‘void Parser::Includes(const rust::cxxbridge1::Vec<rust::cxxbridge1::String>&) const’:
warning: src/cpp/parser.cpp:22:54: warning: unused parameter ‘includes’ [-Wunused-parameter]
warning:    22 | void Parser::Includes(const rust::Vec<rust::String> &includes) const {
warning:       |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
   Compiling cpp-rules v0.1.0 (/home/username/repos/cpp-rules)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" "/tmp/rustczOwWPb/symbols.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.1008qgme4q63djgz.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.1249j3tvn1y25h6c.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.17lpu485lvehx0px.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.18sg5hvxsxi6pzj4.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.192mislfobnjnpyj.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.1aasme8g66am3cn8.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.1yf1mog17v68i1ch.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.2h8bnaeygmd91fz.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.2nhqs3w80eqh3h04.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.2sgko118h55x5wnu.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.2usi4oxw7rhl83xt.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.39deh2s9d1oslum9.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.3a2vyfdfu3o05n0b.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.3chuhoxfcyrjnfs5.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.3vdsuottgx76lux.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.3x7pm18i5iancyih.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.3zjckvfkhuw6w51w.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.46jea8rhpbkmaem1.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.46ztdt6t0w1n8ro5.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.49strxboh6jnpvpp.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.4dj9ib29i8lnop7s.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.4epwar3ysc13p1mi.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.4r6odqajxcsoapgy.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.4t3u9ci2hd4c9z79.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.4zukduhgspn7a43v.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.54mc800jv73ic2b0.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.55jknfdhmopkzxuk.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.58n2rpv2ymsv73zf.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.cnwdplgl6pisy4n.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.d793tq8k7cnrp4t.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.fbyn2o0rf673t7c.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.g9e60hd8zoza2wk.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.o7y6d2bxts45eyr.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.tv9vyxerboqmv2j.rcgu.o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1.5epkm5t0llgu1q4q.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/build/cpp-rules-7f41b8ce72eba842/out/build" "-L" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/build/cpp-rules-7f41b8ce72eba842/out" "-L" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/build/cxx-c0fec50dc6f39ebf/out" "-L" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/build/link-cplusplus-7517e535596e121b/out" "-L" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-lcppparser" "-lcpp-rules" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/libcxx-ecdd82004ef2f5d0.rlib" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/liblink_cplusplus-22452e976b210b65.rlib" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/libanyhow-acde19e659b2b89e.rlib" "-Wl,--start-group" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-91db243dd05c003b.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-72269a4525d4f5cf.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-28d8f1c01a28b12d.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-5b78018a9f8ae4bc.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-f4160de9657f17b2.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-1cd8b958acdf2395.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-a4c4a7e7edfa8aea.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-061c02acc74ada37.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-2aed706f056a5dfb.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-1e1f90ff4bfdca6f.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-2d16c932daf0ad41.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-8f15fae89f489a33.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-81f3d85dace75e64.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-e071db8735f10456.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-6db7e05a8de4df10.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-7c03f666869e802a.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-2a6a2797f7a73818.rlib" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-0e3656b1fda5fd7b.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-b09abe545ed38eb1.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lstdc++" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-znoexecstack" "-L" "/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/deps/cpp_rules-fa9509d567369da1" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/username/repos/cpp-rules/target/debug/build/cpp-rules-7f41b8ce72eba842/out/libcpp-rules.a(parser.o): in function `Parser::Parser(rust::cxxbridge1::String)':
          /home/username/repos/cpp-rules/src/cpp/parser.cpp:13: undefined reference to `CppParser::CppParser(std::unique_ptr<CppObjFactory, std::default_delete<CppObjFactory> >)'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/username/repos/cpp-rules/src/cpp/parser.cpp:14: undefined reference to `CppParser::setErrorHandler(std::function<void (char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, int)>)'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/username/repos/cpp-rules/src/cpp/parser.cpp:19: undefined reference to `CppParser::parseFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

  = help: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)

The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: src/cpp/parser.cpp: In lambda function:
warning: src/cpp/parser.cpp:14:83: warning: unused parameter ‘errorStartPos’ [-Wunused-parameter]
warning:    14 |     parser.setErrorHandler([file](const char* errLineText, size_t lineNum, size_t errorStartPos, int lexerContext) -> void {
warning:       |                                                                            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: src/cpp/parser.cpp:14:102: warning: unused parameter ‘lexerContext’ [-Wunused-parameter]
warning:    14 |     parser.setErrorHandler([file](const char* errLineText, size_t lineNum, size_t errorStartPos, int lexerContext) -> void {
warning:       |                                                                                                  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: src/cpp/parser.cpp: In member function ‘void Parser::Includes(const rust::cxxbridge1::Vec<rust::cxxbridge1::String>&) const’:
warning: src/cpp/parser.cpp:22:54: warning: unused parameter ‘includes’ [-Wunused-parameter]
warning:    22 | void Parser::Includes(const rust::Vec<rust::String> &includes) const {
warning:       |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

error: could not compile `cpp-rules` due to previous error
```

#### Directory structure of cpp-rules:

```
├── build.rs
├── Cargo.toml
├── common https://github.com/satya-das/common
├── CppParser https://github.com/satya-das/cppparser
├── src
│   ├── cpp
│   │   ├── parser.cpp
│   │   ├── parser.h
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── rules.rs
```

#### build.rs

```rs
fn main() {
    let dir = cmake::Config::new("CppParser").build_target("cppparser").build();
    let dir = dir.join("build");
    let dir = dir.to_str().unwrap();

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", dir);
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=cppparser");

    cxx_build::bridge("src/rules.rs")
        .include("CppParser/pub")
        .include("src/cpp")
        .file("src/cpp/parser.cpp")
        .flag("-std=c++17")
        .flag(&format!("-L {}", dir))
        .flag("-lcppparser")
        .compile("cpp-rules");

    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/rules.rs");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/cpp/parser.cpp");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/cpp/parser.h");
}
```

#### rules.rs

```
#[cxx::bridge]
pub mod ffi {
    unsafe extern "C++" {
        include!("cpp-rules/src/cpp/parser.h");

        type Parser;
        fn new_parser(file: String) -> UniquePtr<Parser>;
        fn Includes(&self, includes: &Vec<String>);
    }
}
```

#### main.rs

```
mod rules;

use anyhow::Result;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let parser = rules::ffi::new_parser("../hello-world.cpp".to_string());
    let mut includes: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    parser.Includes(&mut includes);

    println!("{:?}", includes);

    Ok(())
}
```

#### parser.h

```
#pragma once

#include "rust/cxx.h"
#include "../../CppParser/pub/cppparser.h"

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

typedef uint64_t u64;

class Parser {
public:
    Parser() = default;
    ~Parser() = default;
    Parser(rust::String file);
    void Includes(const rust::Vec<rust::String> &includes) const;
private:
    CppCompoundPtr ast;
    CppParser parser;
};

std::unique_ptr<Parser> new_parser(rust::String file);
```

#### parser.cpp

```
#include "cpp-rules/src/rules.rs.h"
#include "cpp-rules/src/cpp/parser.h"
#include "../../CppParser/pub/cppparser.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

std::unique_ptr<Parser> new_parser(rust::String file) {
    return std::make_unique<Parser>(file);
}

Parser::Parser(rust::String file) {
    parser.setErrorHandler([file](const char* errLineText, size_t lineNum, size_t errorStartPos, int lexerContext) -> void {
        std::cout << "Could not parse: " << file << ". Error at: " << std::to_string(lineNum) << "\n" << errLineText << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    });

    ast = parser.parseFile(std::string(file));
}

void Parser::Includes(const rust::Vec<rust::String> &includes) const {
    // auto members = ast->members();
    
    // u64 n = members.size();
    // for (u64 i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    // }
}
```

Comment: 32 bit vs 64 bit library conflict? (just a total guess)

Comment: @john nope, just checked, my compiled c++ and cppparser libs are 64 bit :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking order was the culprit.

Use [extra-link-arg](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/reference/unstable.html?highlight=extra-link-arg#extra-link-arg) or [rustc-link-arg](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#rustc-link-arg) to add link command at the end.